# Formatting Specific Parts of a Listview Item

Tags: java, android, listview, formatting, textview

So in my application I am using a ListView to display data from an ArrayList which holds objects. The data is displayed using the same method as the tutorial on the android developer website:

```
        // automatically adds a ListView to fill the entire screen of this activity
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Part>(this, R.layout.list_item, Main.parts));
    ListView lv = getListView();        

    // allows the user to start typing to filter the list
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);       

    // set the click listener for each list item
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

The objects are currently displayed in each list_item:

```
<!-- Defines the layout for each item being placed in the ListView. -->
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

So I return each object as such:

```
    public String toString() {
    return "Item Number: " + itemNmbr + "\nPrice: " + price + "\nDescription: " + desc;
}
```

An example of how the list currently looks:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/689/devicet.png/

The problem is, I need to format the title separately from the data. (because it needs to be bold, and possibly spaced out a little further.)

Any ideas? I'm currently testing on how to get two textviews to work together.

Thank you!

Comment: Here is what I ended up doing:

http://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a custom adapter extending BaseAdapter.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html

See this link for an example.

http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

Comment: Thanks. This led me in the right direction, I'll post up some sample code in a bit just in case anyone else needs some guidance for something like this - I found a few of the things that developer did were somewhat un-needed.